# List<Object> no me devuelve los datos que quiero

Tags: java, spring

Estoy haciendo una query que me devuelve por ejemplo [101,18], [101,21], pero al intentar simplemente pintar lo que lleva la query me devuelve:

```
  [Ljava.lang.Object;@6f563af5
  [Ljava.lang.Object;@789eaaa5
```

Mi código:

```
List<Object> list101 = remService.getTipoDocYEntidad(idEnvioRemesa);
       for(Object o1: list101) {
           System.out.println(o1);
}
```

Debugeando se ve que los arrays llegan correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es conseguir imprimir cada elemento, porque posteriormente quiero añadir a cada lista un elemento más

Comment: Lo que tú quieres es una cosa, lo que tú le pides a Java que haga es otra completamente diferente. Puede que no pinte lo que tú quieres, pero desde luego que está pintando lo que tú le indicas que pinte... verás, el método `toString` de `Object` por defecto te pinta LA REFERENCIA DEL OBJETO. Eso es lo que sucede cuando haces `System.out.println(o1);`. Si quieres que pinte otra cosa te recomiendo que A) uses una clase propia tuya en vez de un `Object` y sobreescribas el método `toString()` o B) hagas un método que reciba el `Object` y te devuelva el String formateado como tu quieres :)

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes es que estás pasando a `System.out.println` un array. El método println tiene que transformar el objeto que le pasas a un String para poder mostrarlo y, para ello, delega en el método `toString()` que tienen todos los objetos.

Pero todos los objetos tienen este método porque lo heredan de Object, por lo que ese método sólo pinta la dirección de memoria del objeto, ya que no tiene propiedades/atributos que mostrar.

Puedes modificar tu código usando `Arrays.toString()`:

```
for(Object o1: list101) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[])o1);
}
```

Comment: ¿Y no es posible acceder a un elemento en concreto por ejemplo del primer array de la lista sin que varíe su tipo? Es decir, si quiere acceder al primer array, y coger el primer y segundo elemento, no me deja. ¿Debo de hacer algún tipo de conversión?¿Y sí son más tipos diferente y quiero conservar el Object?